# Firestore returns sorted list of docs when I only want to filter

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am building an e-commerce app. I am using Firestore as my database. I want to filter products based on category and price range. Firebase requires creating an index "category Ascending price Ascending". And I get a list of products belonging to that category and in the given price range. However, the returned list is also sorted by price.

How can I disable sorting by price?

Edit:
I am using FireSQL for querying my Firestore database. Below I included a part of my React app.

```
    var sqlQuery = 'SELECT * FROM products WHERE';

    if(selectedCategories.length > 0) {
        var categoryQuery = "('" + selectedCategories.join("','") + "')";
        sqlQuery += ` category IN ${categoryQuery} AND`;
    }

    sqlQuery += ` (price >= ${PriceLowerBound} AND price <= ${PriceUpperBound})`

    fireSQL.query(sqlQuery).then(documents => {
        setProductList(documents);
    });
```

I currently have 4 products:

1. product1: category: "c1", price 189
2. product2: category: "c2", price 178
3. product3: category: "c1", price 128
4. product4: category: "c1", price 298

Suppose no category was selected then the query will be *SELECT * FROM products WHERE (price >= 128 AND price <= 298)*, and I will get products in following order:

1. product3: category: "c1", price 128
2. product2: category: "c2", price 178
3. product1: category: "c1", price 189
4. product4: category: "c1", price 298

When I run this query for the first time, firebase gave me an error and a link, and I created the following index: *"category Ascending price Ascending"*. Because of this index, I am getting products where the price is sorted in ascending order. However, I expect to get products in the previous order.

I give users the ability to change PriceLowerBound and PriceUpperBound, add/remove categories to filter. I also want to add "ORDER BY price ASC/DESC" option too. So, I do not want products to be sorted when I do not write "ORDER BY" part.

Comment: Please post what have you tried so far

Answer (score 0):

You should post what you've tried so far, as @Ashish suggested. We don't even know which language you're using. :-)

But for Javascript, something like the below would be a start.

```
let minPrice = 45;
let maxPrice = 300;
let productCat = "mugs";
const query = db.collection("products").where("price", ">=", minPrice).where("price", "<=" maxPrice).where("category", "==", productCat).get();
```

But this won't be enough. For Firestore to keep queries fast, it needs to combine "category" and "price" in a new index. It's an index where category and price are tied together in a long table with corresponding document Ids.

In other words, they *have* to be ordered for you to get your query results very quickly.

Your solution would be to order them again on the client-side in a way that makes sense for your business case.

If you can post your code, we could give you an example of how to order the results you get from Firestore on the client-side.